# Traverse an associative array followed by a string pattern?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional associative array as follows

```php
$data = Array
(
    [store_name] => Jota
    [social] => Array
        (
            [fb] => 78
            [youtube] => 34
            [twitter] => 97
            [linkedin] => 23
            [pinterest] => 12
            [instagram] => 93
            [flickr] => 45
        )
)
```

Input to my program is a **string** that is compose of keys from the above array separated by brackets. E.g

```php
$input = "data[social][fb]"
```

Question 1
How can I traverse the above array as per the input string pattern & access the value of `$data["social"]["fb"]`?

Question 2

How can I update the value in the above array followed by a string pattern?

```php
$pattern = "data[social][fb];
$value = "foo";
update_array( $data,  $pattern, $value);
```

Comment: Why use that type of string `data[social][fb]`???  Use something easier to work with.

Comment: I have a beginning for you: `explode('[', str_replace(']', '', "data[social][fb]")); // ["data", "social", "fb"]` but then you gotta loop over the elements to drill down. (Probably can do this more elegantly with Regex, I'm sure someone will suggest)

Comment: I also asked this same question over 5 years ago and got a good script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334635/dynamically-accessing-multidimensional-array-value

Comment: @PhilTune  But you are using an actual array not a string that sorta looks like an array.

Comment: There's no reason to do it this way, but if you quote the keys in the string then https://3v4l.org/nHlAm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the keys with a regular expression and then iteratively dig into the data structure:

```
function getDeep($data, $str) {
    preg_match_all("#\[(.*?)\]#", $str, $keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    foreach ($keys[1] as $key) $data = $data[$key];
    return $data;
}
```

Run like this:

```
$data = [
    "store_name" => "Jota",
    "social" => [
            "fb" => 78,
            "youtube" => 34,
            "twitter" => 97,
            "linkedin" => 23,
            "pinterest" => 12,
            "instagram" => 93,
            "flickr" => 45,
    ]
];

$input = "data[social][fb]";
echo getDeep($data, $input);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have updated my post with a Q2. You may have a look please.

Comment: I see the Q2, but a Stack Overflow question should be one question only. Also, as you have seen this answer, this should give you ideas to solve it yourself. Please have a go at it, and if you cannot make it work, then ask a completely new question about it, including your attempt, and the problem with it.